# iOS Swift Scrollview Set Frame Position Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, cgrect, cgrectmake

I am have scrollview in my app. By default `y` position of my scrollview is `80`. In some locations I need to move `y` position of my scrollview to `0`. Here is the code

```
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.ScrollView.delegate = self
   if(Position == "changed")
   {
      self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.ScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.ScrollView.frame.size.height)
   }
   else
   {
      self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: self.ScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.ScrollView.frame.size.height)
   }
}
```

But this code won't works.

Comment: Checkout my answer, might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936110/how-to-load-a-uiviewcontroller-inside-an-uiscrollview/39937248#39937248

Comment: When you want to change the position of the ScrollView?

Comment: I am loading this same page from multiple view. If position value equals to `changed` I need to change the position

Comment: @Aakash Sorry, I not able to get it clearly. Can you pls code me clearly

Comment: uncheck adjust scrollview insets from  try again

Comment: Set the frame of scrollView in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method not in viewDidLoad()

Comment: if you are using autolayout then you need to add Scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false before setting its frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will not able to set Scrollview Position in `viewDidLoad()` so Add those code in `viewDidAppear()`. Final Code Here

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
     DispatchQueue.main.async
     {
          self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.ScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.ScrollView.frame.size.height + 80)
     }
}
```

Comment: if your VC embed in navigation controller , the UI will render correctly for your concept if you navigate once to another VC and come back

Answer (score 1):

problem is simple your VC.view not updated in Viewdidload, so in here you need to move the UI updation on  Viewdidappear or update the UI in main thread

by default your `self.ScrollView.frame` is started in **O** position, so only check with **!=**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.ScrollView.delegate = self
   //self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.ScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.ScrollView.frame.size.height)
   if(Position != "changed")
   {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: self.ScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.ScrollView.frame.size.height)
    }

   }

}
```

Comment: change your ScrollView contentsize also

Comment: It works but I write those codes inside `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @KavinKumarArumugam - choice is urs , happy day