# How to add UIViewController into UIScrollView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I want to add UIViewController into UIScrollView.
I searching and tried, but I can't find solution.
The most understandable way is [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39937248)

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView.contentSize.width = self.view.frame.width * 2


        let test = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test") as! TestViewController

        self.addChild(test)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(test.view)
        test.willMove(toParent: self)

        test.view.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
    }
}
```

But, I this way is error like this.
[image]
[image]

How to add UIViewController into UIScrollView??
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, just drag and drop a `containerView`, it will make a `UIViewController`
in your `scrollView` as you want

Comment: maybe this could help you more
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370801/how-to-add-a-container-view-programmatically

Comment: yeah it helped me.